# android picker in 2 parts only

Tags: android, picker

I want to implement a picker that will have only 2 part. consider the following image
[image]

In this i want to remove 2008 part of the picker. and also please let me know how to get control on title so that we can change the title and we can remove the title (if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could experiment with creating a subclass of the `DatePickerDialog` but I don't think you have direct access to manipulate the layout of it that much. You might be able to control the title, but not which of the pickers are shown.

I think it would be faster and easier to create your own PickerDialog with the desired layout using `NumberPicker`.

**Edit: Links on Custom Dialogs**

[Custom Android Dialog](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/)

[Android Developers - CustomDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

[Android Series - Creating Custom Dialog](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-creating-custom-dialogs/)

Comment: Thanks kasperMoerch...can you provide me an example for it?

Comment: You should experiment on that yourself - you won't learn much if I just give you the full working code. I'll post some links above to give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you cannot customize DatePickerDialog, so let try third party library such as DateSlider.
http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/